# how to store multiple images from vue3-axios via laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-7

i am trying to retrieve the uploaded image. The following code is used to upload images:

```
<v-file-input
  ref="file" 
  @change="handleFileUpload"  
  type="file"
  show-size
  counter
  multiple
  label="File input"
/>
const files = ref(null)
const file = ref(null)
const handleFileUpload = function() {
  files.value = file.value.files;
}

const onSubmit = () => {
      refForm.value?.validate().then(({ valid }) => {
        if (valid) {
          console.log(files.value)
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file',files.value)
          axios.post(laroute.route('api.project.single.store').slice(4), formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
          })
```

// files.value

```
FileList {0: File, length: 1}
0: File {
     name: '2.PNG', 
     lastModified: 1665851574959, 
     lastModifiedDate: Sat Oct 15 2022 23:32:54 GMT+0700, 
     webkitRelativePath: '', 
     size: 205548, ...
   }
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: FileList
```

data is sent when i view in browser

```
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

[object FileList]
------WebKitFormBoundary--
```

laravel api

```
return $request->file; //[object FileList]
return $request->hasFile('file'); //space
```

Can someone help me.
Thanks in advance!